# how I can optimize the code of my trait to avoid having two attributes of the same value in the child class

Tags: php, traits, php-7.4

I have this code and something seems wrong to me. The fact that I have to assign the same value to two different attributes. One from my trait and the other from my current class.

I wish I could completely isolate my trait and not have to make this assignment in my child class constructor.

Code:

```php
interface ARepoInterface extends BaseRepoInterface {}

interface BRepoInterface extends BaseRepoInterface {}


trait Foo {
    protected BaseRepoInterface $repo;

    public function method(array $array): void {
      // Do stuff with $repo
    }
}

class A
{
    private ARepoInterface $ARepo;
    protected BaseRepoInterface $repo;

    use Foo;

    public function __construct(ARepoInterface $ARepo)
    {
        //@todo This is weird
        $this->ARepo = $this->repo = $ARepo;
    }
    //Other methods
}

class B
{
    private BRepoInterface $BRepo;
    protected BaseRepoInterface $repo;

    use Foo;

    public function __construct(BRepoInterface $BRepo)
    {
        //@todo This is weird
        $this->BRepo = $this->repo = $BRepo;
    }
    //Other methods
}
```

Thank you in advance for your advice

Comment: Why not have the same name for each repo (in trait, and both clases) and you should be able to use it

Comment: Because ARepo and BRepo represent something different and in my classes, I'm using other repos.

Answer (score 0):

In fact PHP doesn't care much about the type hinting, so one property is enough for you.

```
interface ARepoInterface extends BaseRepoInterface { public function A(); }

class A
{
    use Foo;

    public function __construct(ARepoInterface $ARepo)
    {
        $this->repo = $ARepo;
    }

    public function methodDoStuffWithARepoInterface()
    {
        $this->repo->A();
    }
}
```

And don't worry, intellisense still works.